# hide/show elements on click JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three links on top, Logos (#logos), Business cards (#businesscards), Flyers (#flyers)

By default, "Logos" link is highlighted with content (#logos-container) showing. 
When clicking "Business cards", Business cards content (#businesscards-container) will show with other content hidden.
When clicking "Flyers", Flyers (#flyers-container) content will show with others hidden.

This is my code:

[Javascript]

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#businesscards-container").hide();
        $("#flyers-container").hide();
        $("#logos").click(function () {
            $("#businesscards-container").hide();
            $("#flyers-container").hide();
            $("#logos-container").show();
        });
        $("#businesscards").click(function () {
            $("#logos-container").hide();
            $("#flyers-container").hide();
            $("#businesscards-container").show();
        });
        $("#flyers").click(function () {
            $("#logos-container").hide();
            $("#businesscards-container").hide();
            $("#flyers-container").show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

[html]

```
<div id="front-nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="#logos"><a href="#logos">Logos</a></li>
        <li id="#businesscards"><a href="#businesscards">Business cards</a></li>
        <li id="#flyers" style="padding-right:60px; border-right:none;"><a href="#flyers">Flyers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="logos-container">
</div>

<div id="businesscards-container">
</div>

<div id="flyers-container">
</div>
```

The default is working, but not when I click on other links. I tried adding e.preventDefault but no results. How should I go about this?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Resolved! Thank you.

Comment: What is the markup for the elements you are clicking?

Comment: We'll need a complete code example. Please post your HTML and CSS. Also a jsFiddle.net example would be helpful.

Comment: Make JSFiddle demo,because this is not helpful so much

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed solution - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mh6mU/2/)

```
#flyers-container {

    display: none;
}

#businesscards-container {

    display: none;
}
```

Initially just add display none to divs you wanna hide.. and waa laaa

Answer (score 0):

you should set the default display on the php page for all the containers. I assume logos is the default display.

```
<div id="logos" style="display:block;">
   <!-- some code -->
</div>
<div id="businesscards" style="display:none;">
   <!-- some code -->
</div>
<div id="flyers" style="display:none;">
   <!-- some code -->
</div>
```

then the JavaScript will handle the show and hide of the elements

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that they are links, you need to prevent default behaviour,try do try this:

```
    $("#logos").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#businesscards-container").hide();
        $("#flyers-container").hide();
        $("#logos-container").show();
    });
    $("#businesscards").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#logos-container").hide();
        $("#flyers-container").hide();
        $("#businesscards-container").show();
    });
    $("#flyers").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#logos-container").hide();
        $("#businesscards-container").hide();
        $("#flyers-container").show();
    });
```